# ggplot2 colorbar with discontinuous jump for skewed data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some fake data, `x` and `y`, with color information `z`.  `z` is highly skewed, and as such renders the colorbar uninformative:

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- x + rnorm(N)
z <- x+y+rnorm(N)
z[z>2] <- z[z>2]+exp(z[z>2]-2)
d <- data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, color = z)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I'd like to have most of the colorbar reflect the main range of the the data, but have a box for overflows, say above 5.  Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in ggplot2?  Note that I would like the colorbar to remain continuous, rather than discrete, for most of its range.  I'll probably either discretize or topcode if what I want isn't feasible.

Comment: That's better than top-coding the input data, but it doesn't make the skewed observations have their own color.  I'm not sure that what I want is possible without discretizing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that general plot, although the legends would need more work:

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, color = z)) + geom_point(size = 5)

p + scale_color_gradient2(
  low = 'green', high = 'red', mid = 'grey80', na.value = 'blue', limits= c(-10, 10)
)
```

You can cheat in some extra legend fluff, e.g.:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, color = z, alpha = '>10')) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_gradient2(
    low = 'green', high = 'red', mid = 'grey80', na.value = 'blue', limits= c(-10, 10),
    guide = guide_colorbar(title.position = 'left')
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = 1, name = 'z', 
    guide = guide_legend(
      override.aes = list(color = 'blue'), title.position = 'left', 
      title.theme = element_text(color = 'white', angle = 0)
    )
  ) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(-5, 10, -5, 10))
```

[image]

Note that red/green pallets are bad for the color impaired.

Comment: That's a start!  I guess internally `scale_color_gradient2` sets oob's to NA?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'll try and have a quick and dirty legend in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon Axeman's answer I came up with the following slight hack to get blues into your color scale:

First, define a color map with 20 colors for the values within and 5 for the  values outside your range.

```
cmap <- colorRampPalette(c("green","grey80","red"))(20)
cmap <- append(cmap,rep("blue",5))
```

Then cut the z values into 20 chunks between -10 and 10 and convert to numeric (resulting in NA's for values above 10). By specifying the cmap in scale_color_gradientn and limits of [1,25] we map values of -10 to 1 (green) and 10 to 20 (red). Finally by specifying breaks we manually add the correct labels (i.e. the 5th category corresponds to values between -6 and -5).

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, color=as.numeric(cut(z, breaks=seq(-10,10))))) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors=cmap, limits=c(1,25), breaks=c(5,11,17,23),
                        labels=c(-6,0,6,">10"), name="z", na.value = "blue")
```

[Lovely result :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9HTv.png)

The only issue is that you will have to make sure that no values will ever fall below -10 as they would also be shown in blue as well using this method.